# Orient DB Issues with 64 Bit JVM

Tags: java, orientdb

IN orient DB when I enter server.bat from the command prompt, I get the message

> Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please
>   install the desired version.

How to resolve it.

My Java version

```
C:\Orientdb\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle's download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) get **Java x86** marked installer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is associated with your System looking for a Java 64-bit Virtual Machine and not finding any.
To solve it, you must make sure that the 64-bit Java is installed.go to java site and use 64 bit java .